# Show a Pandas dataframe with python in pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

I'm working with **Pycharm** and I am not able to use the debugger mode to use the "View as Dataframe" just it is suggested [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-as-array.html).

I would like to know if any libraries are availables to show me up my entire dataframe. I see that many people use Jupyter and any of them have this problem.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve exactly. If you're using Jupyter you can just execute a cell with just the content `df` to display the data frame in a tabular layout.

Comment: I'm using Pycharm. Here it is uncomfortable to simply print out the df print(df), because if you have many cols, it won't show all of them. So I'm asking if there is a library to show the whole dataframe. (Please, forget about Jupyter)

Comment: You could either disable the maximum number of printed columns by using `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)` or disable the maximum number of printed characters by using `pd.set_option('display.width', None)`. Of course swapping `None` with an integer of your choice sets the limit to your desired value.

Comment: This has been really helpful, thanks. But it is not comfortable. I would like a library useful to show my df in a new window and scroll down all the features and observations.

Comment: Why do you think you cannot use the debugger mode?

Comment: I can use it. But it doesn't show me any dataframes or variables, and I don't know why yet. Following those instructions I see only empty variables or df

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm a little late to the game, but somebody somehow may find this useful in the future:

https://tech-notes.maxmasnick.com/pycharm-view-dataframe-or-series-using-sciview-from-the-evaluate-window-with-a-keyboard-shortcut

Essentially: Use the SciView Panel and change from "Plots" to "Data". Enter the name of your dataframe (Presumably *df*) into the expression field at the bottom.

Comment: the link provided is broke